# When changing device orientation, I lose text input, how can I fix this

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I have a countdown timer application, and when I change the orientation from vertical to horizontal on my phone, the countdown text no longer displays, and when I switch it back it does not come back, unless, I hit start again, which shouldn't be there in the first place, because the button changes to pause when it starts, but when I flip it, the countdown indicator goes blank and the button says start, even though the countdown is running, and displays an onFinish().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind I found it. I had set my orientation in my layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

all I had to do from there on is add this to my AndroidManifest in the  I was working with.

```
    <activity android:name="TimerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

And voala!

Comment: Just to comment on this, the orientation of your LinearLayout has nothing to do with the orientation of your phone. It only specifies in what direction child elements are placed within the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity gets restarted, you'll want to override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` which is specifically called in this scenario before the activity is destroyed. Threre's an [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) on the android site that covers this in detail.

Comment: Would having a part of my code, that sends the countdown into a service fix this problem? And I was also thinking temporarily, can I lock the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

that's because Dalvik vm destroy the activity and creates a new one when you device is rotating, so, you have to find someway to save the state of the activity and his childs, maybe overriding one of the methods, onFinish(), onStop() or onDestroy()